# How do I upgrade my MacPorts Perl installation?

Tags: perl, applet, osx-snow-leopard, macports

I have installed MacPorts in my MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard. I hadn't explicitly installed perl there but I guess it either came installed with the default macports install or was installed as a dependency by any other port I installed.

I want to upgrade the Perl v5.8.9 there with the latest stable Perl version. Whichever it may be currently (I see it is 5.12.2). So, my question is simply how do I do a complete replacement of the old Perl with the new in macports.

Will `sudo port upgrade perl5` work or do I need to do something else as well. I just wanted to make sure this was the right command so as to avoid screwing up my macports install.

Comment: perl is easy to compile and install without MacPorts. You might try it by hand once to see for yourself. :)

Comment: yeah i kinda know that i can install the new perl without MacPorts but that is besides the point. I usually keep the default Perl install from Apple and try out new versions in the MacPorts install. I was just looking for the correct way to do that IN MacPorts :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`port upgrade packagename` is the right form, yes.

But i think that in this case, it's a bit trickier than that.

Have a look at the perl5 [portfile](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/lang/perl5/Portfile). It's a wrapper which simply depends on perl 5.8. If you just `sudo port upgrade perl5`, it won't get you to 5.12. However, the perl5 package has a couple of variants for 5.10 and 5.12. You should be able to see all this locally with `port variants perl5`.

What i'm not sure about is whether you can pass variant flags (`+perl5_12` in this case) to `port upgrade`, or whether you need to do a new `port install` on top of your current installation. Or even, horror of horrors, uninstall the current package before installing the variant.

The whole variant mechanism was a mistake, IMHO. An interesting and worthwhile experiment, but one from which we've learned it was a bad idea.

EDIT: i think you can add a variant to an installed port; it seems you have to say:

```
sudo port deactivate perl5
sudo port install perl5 +perl5_12
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to uninstall `perl5.8` before installing `perl5.12`:

```
sudo port deactivate perl5.8
sudo port uninstall perl5.8
sudo port install perl5 +perl5_12
```

Note: If uninstalling `perl5.8` fails, you might force the uninstall by

```
sudo port uninstall -f perl5.8
```

**WARNING**: This *might* break other packages' dependencies.

But so far, it did the job for `perl` (and for me):

```
% perl -v

This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 2 (v5.12.2) built for darwin-multi-2level
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this when moving from Perl 5.26 to 5.28:

- `$ sudo vi /opt/local/etc/macports/variants.conf` to add `+perl5_28` (using emacs is allowed :-)
- `$ port depend perl5.26 | awk '!/p5.26/ { print $1 }' | xargs sudo port install` to upgrade perl, git and the like to sit on top of the new variant
- `$ sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents perl5.26` to eliminate Perl 5.26.

Comment: You have the most promising answer, except I think you have a typo in the second command, because `port depend perl5.26 | awk '!/p5.26/ { print $1 }' will always be empty, the first part finds all perl5.26 dependencies and the second part removes them again..

Comment: Also your third command follow dependents uninstalls too much

Comment: @Born2Smile In fact that second command aims at finding the ports that depend upon perl5.26 and don't have `p5.26` in their name.   This is to get rid of all the Perl packages, such as `p5.26-authen-sasl`, etc.  They will be installed by the perl5.28 package.  In my case the second command finds git, ossp-uuid and perl 5.

Comment: I realised as much looking at `port depend perl5.26`. Printing the same packages as you and the p5.26*. But, silly me forgot the 'p' in 'p5.26' when typing your awk command, and my brain did not notice the discrepancy when I made the comment. The second comment however is real enough, as I pasted that in verbatim only to find clang and neomutt also uninstalled though they did not appear in `port depend perl5.26`, but each depended on perl5