# Macports warning: Can't rebuild Perl extension p5.26-net-ssleay

Tags: perl, openssl, macports

On macOS/High Sierra (10.13.6) with perl (v5.26.3) I cannot rebuild `p5.26-net-ssleay` with MacPorts (2.7.1). After upgrading with `sudo port selfupdate`, I get

```
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  Found 2 broken files, matching files to ports      
Warning: No port p5.26-net-ssleay found in the index; can't rebuild
```

I know that this port has been deleted recently.

How do I fix this warning? Should I upgrade to perl (p5.28)?

Comment: *"upgrading with 'sudo port'"* Did you mean  running `sudo port selfupdate` ?

Comment: According to [this](https://ports.macports.org/port/p5.26-net-ssleay/) page, it says that `p5.26-net-ssleay` has been deleted. But there exists a version for Perl version 5.28 [here](https://ports.macports.org/port/p5.28-net-ssleay/)

Comment: What version of perl are you using currently? Please provide output of `perl --version` and `which perl`

Comment: `perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level` and standard path `/opt/local/bin/perl`

Comment: Ok good, you are using v 5.26.. I am not familiar with MacPorts, but I think it would be safest to upgrade to Perl version 5.28 before installing p5.28-net-ssleay. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942520/how-do-i-upgrade-my-macports-perl-installation) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion to upgrade to Perl V5.28 (see [how to upgrade from V5.26 to V5.28](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54086312/10063208)) solves, on the one hand, the warning issue but on the other side, *all* previous installed packages that depend on V5.26 are also uninstalled and have to be reinstalled again.